# Remix reverting when passing ether value

Tags: contract-development

I am trying to pass ether from one contract to another in remix, but it is throwing error and reverts, when I create "EtherTransferFrom" contract with value other than 0. Can you kindly check and help?

https://github.com/willitscale/learning-solidity/blob/master/tutorial-14/EtherTransfer.sol

Answer (score 0):

You must first deploy `EtherTransferTo` and note its address lets say it is 0x123....

Then when you new up your `_instance` you pass in that address.

```
function EtherTransferFrom() public {
  _instance = new EtherTransferTo(0x123....);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But even one empty contract (while trying to debug), with one empty payable function, also throws same VM error.